# In D2RQ, I run d2r-server.bat kg_movie.ttl,but got an error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: java, d2rq

I want to use D2RQ to start a service,so I run d2r-server.bat kg_movie.ttl, but got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.UPropertyAliases.<clinit>(UPropertyAliases.java:87)
    at com.ibm.icu.lang.UCharacter.<clinit>(UCharacter.java:5680)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.CharacterModel.isComposingChar(CharacterModel.java:147)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.ParserSupport.checkComposingChar(ParserSupport.java:128)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.states.AbsWantLiteralValueOrDescription.characters(AbsWantLiteralValueOrDescription.java:59)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.states.WantTypedLiteral.characters(WantTypedLiteral.java:28)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.characters(XMLHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.characters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.characters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.characters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:155)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:173)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:160)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:232)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:268)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.findMetadata(OntDocumentManager.java:894)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.initialiseMetadata(OntDocumentManager.java:852)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.<init>(OntDocumentManager.java:200)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.<init>(OntDocumentManager.java:182)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.<init>(OntDocumentManager.java:166)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntDocumentManager.getInstance(OntDocumentManager.java:244)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec.getDocumentManager(OntModelSpec.java:339)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.getDocumentManager(OntModelImpl.java:181)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.loadImports(OntModelImpl.java:1973)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.<init>(OntModelImpl.java:147)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.<init>(OntModelImpl.java:119)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(ModelFactory.java:359)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.parser.MapParser.<init>(MapParser.java:85)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.SystemLoader.getMapping(SystemLoader.java:300)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.SystemLoader.getModelD2RQ(SystemLoader.java:323)
    at d2rq.server.run(server.java:65)
    at de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.CommandLineTool.process(CommandLineTool.java:158)
    at d2rq.server.main(server.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
    at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:188)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
    ... 40 more
```

The file "kg_movie.ttl" does not have any problems, so I don't know why? any answer will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide the command you use to run the Service. It will helpful

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/d2rq/d2rq/issues/322 ,a possible reason,java version.and, we are working on similar projects